# HTML directly after ASP call. No space inbetween

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I've got what seemed like a simple issue, but I've yet to find the syntax to figure it out.

I want to use part of my model to change the class name of a div.

```
<div class="@module.FileType SmallIcon"></div>
```

The issue is, if Filetype="cvw", the code above gives me the class name "cvw SmallIcon" when I want "cvwSmallIcon"

I've tried using curlys, @:, line breaks, everything I can think of to get rid of the space. No luck. Obviously if I put SmallIcon right bside FileType, it treats it as the whole variable name and I get an error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just because you're using [tag:asp.net-nvc-4] doesn't mean that you're using [tag:asp-classic].  Please learn the difference and tag your questions properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would give

```
@(module.FileType)SmallIcon
```

or

```
@module.FileType+"SmallIcon"
```

a try.